# Add any to complexType

Tags: xsd

I have this XML schema:

```
    <xs:element name="lineinfo">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
          <xs:element name="done" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
        </xs:all>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:long" />
        <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip" />
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

but I want to allow any other extra element in the `lineinfo` tag:

```
   <lineinfo state="assigned" id="175">
      <done>4</done>
      <todo>6</todo>
   </lineinfo>
```

I tried to add `<xs:any />` inside the `<xs:all>`, but it doesn't seem to be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a way to do what I wanted, so I ended up adding all "unwanted" tags in my list, with `minOccurs` set to 0:

```
   <xs:element name="lineinfo">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
          <xs:element name="done" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
          <xs:element name="todo" minOccurs="0" />
          <xs:element name="error" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:all>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:long" />
        <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip" />
      </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 1):

Parent tag of `<xs:any>` are only `choice`, `sequence`. [w3cschools #el_any](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_any.asp)

To use `<xs:any>` put `<xs:sequence>` instead of `<xs:all>`. [w3cschools #any](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_any.asp)

else you could use xs:anyType

> xs:anyType is a type, like xs:integer (though xs:anyType is special
>   in that it can act as a simple or complex type, and it places
>   essentially no restrictions on the tree that it validates -- think of
>   it loosely as the Schema language's analog of java.lang.Object).

A sample use would be:

```
<xsd:element name="value" type="xs:anyType"/>
```

---

Anyway if you want use  below an example taken from [w3cschools #anyattribute](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_anyattribute.asp)

SCHEMA

```
<xs:element name="person">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:anyAttribute/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:attribute name="gender">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="male|female"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

XML

```
<person gender="female">
  <firstname>Hege</firstname>
  <lastname>Refsnes</lastname>
</person>
```

Comment: I got that, but `sequence` would describe the order of the elements. I want the order to be free.

Comment: Yes you're right. Have you tried to use xs:anyType for your solution, in order to remove xs:sequence.

Comment: I would still need the tags' name. I just want the schema to validate that `done` is inside `lineinfo` and ignore any other tags inside it.

Comment: You should use `mixed=true` on complex type of lineinfo. [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_mixed.asp). A mixed complex type element can contain attributes, elements, and text.

Comment: @BartFriederichs have you solved this issue? if yes, how did you solve it?

Comment: I have solved it the issue in my software, but only by adding the elements to my XMLSchema, not by allowing "any" other element besides the one I want.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Can you share with us your solution? :) Add an answer to solve this topic.